# Azure Point to site connection Error 80070057

Tags: azure, vpn

I created my virtual network, gateway, and certificates.  I upload my management certificate and created my VPN client.  I successfully installed the VPN client.  When I attempt to connect I get the following error:

"Custom script (to update your routing table) failed (80070057)."

Tried in 3 different computers (2 windows 7 and 1 2008 R2).

I've been looking around and found that the connection is done if I delete the SetRoute part in the .cms file installed by the client (user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Cm\myConection\myConnection.cms); I then have to set manually all routes and gateways. It works but it's not what I need, because I need the installer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall or routing table on your router if you are using one, try to connect from another location to see whether it is because of your network architecture or not. if all OK and the problem not fixed, try to another range of IP in azure portal for you VPN subnet, sometimes it has conflicts with your local network.